# Is there an R function for selecting words that end with a specific character?

Tags: r, linguistics

I am a confused linguist trying to use R to collect data from twitter.
I have been using the package twitteR and it has been working pretty well with fixed strings, but I'd like to ask it to get tweets that include "querendo + infinitive verb". In Portuguese, verbs in the infinitive always end with the character 'r'. How can I ask for words that end with a specific character?

```
searchtwitteR(" ", n = 1000, lang = pt, locate = Brazil)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lot of ways to do this. Consider `words` as a vector

```
words <- c('rock', 'tempr', 'infinitr', 'end', 'twitter')
```

In base R :

1) Using `endsWith`

```
words[endsWith(words, 'r')]
#[1] "tempr"    "infinitr" "twitter"
```

2) Using `grep`

```
grep('r$', words, value = TRUE)
```

3) `grepl`

```
words[grepl('r$', words)]
```

---

Using `stringr` :

```
library(stringr)
```

1) `str_detect`

```
words[str_detect(words, 'r$')]
```

2) `str_subset`

```
str_subset(words, 'r$')
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `stri_detect` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
words[stri_detect(words, regex = 'r$')]
#[1] "tempr"    "infinitr" "twitter"
```

---

Or with `substring` from `base R`

```
words[substring(words, nchar(words)) == 'r']
```

#### data

```
words <- c('rock', 'tempr', 'infinitr', 'end', 'twitter')
```